# MySQL Workbench. Диаграмма (reverse engineering) базы WordPress не показывает связи между таблицами. Как добавить их отображение?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, wamp, mysql-workbench

Создаю через MySQL Workbench диаграмму связей БД для сайта на WordPress. Таблицы на диаграмме появляются, но не появляются связи между таблицами.

Как можно включить их отображение?

Сайт расположен локально, в качестве сервера WAMP.

Скрин результата

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: быть может их там реально нет? а в кодексе вордпресса просто схематично показано.

Comment: У вас наверняка не прописаны foreing key в таблицах